# Python 3.4 not running tkinter in Console ONLY

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, vizard

When i'm running the program in the IDLE for python 3.4, the program works fine and as intended. However, when using python Console (through python.exe) the Console returns "ImportError:  No Module named tkinter". I am aware of the differences of tkinter (3.x) and Tkinter (2.x) and am sure it is not this. It might be related to the nonstandard Python build I am using, WorldViz's Vizard.

Comment: You could use a `try` block to test your original theory.

Comment: Are you sure the Python console you're getting is from the same version of Python that you're getting with IDLE? What version does it show when you first run `python.exe`?

Comment: I suppose you tried changing it to `Tkinter` and running the program through the console, and it said `ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'`?

Comment: The computer Im using is running the Prgram from "C:\Program Files\WorldViz\Vizard5\bin\python.exe" (Vizard is python based Oculus Rift coding) - as stated by sys.executable. Now I know that this is the problem, how would I go about changing how it starts up? Ps. im running Windows. Thanks for uberfast reply!

Comment: Does Vizard have an implementation of `tkinter`?

Comment: Not that I know of, how do I change the start up of the script over to Python34. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a standard build of Python 3 installed? If so, specify it when you run your program (e.g. `C:\Python34\python.exe myprogram.py`).

Comment: He's not using those; he's using a 3rd party Python build.

Comment: Adding the specification has worked.  Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1):

If your environment variables are pointing to a nonstandard Python build that doesn't include your desired module, you can specify the correct Python build rather than relying on `py` or `python` at the command line:

```
C:\Users\You> C:\Python34\python.exe myprogram.py
```